# How to pass primary key value to DynamoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a nodejs app and I am using putItem() to insert into DynamoDB. The table that I am passing the value to has a primary key called "id". Now what I am trying to do is to generate a UUID and set the primary key value to that UUID whenever I insert the data. However when I insert, the "id" is inserted with double quotes. For eg: instead of `id: 229f0a06-7257-4727-b825-a6e8ea343b1e` it will show as `id : "229f0a06-7257-4727-b825-a6e8ea343b1e"`. I checked the schema and it shows that "id" KeyType is `HASH`. This is the code I have to insert into DB:

```
let data = {};
 data.id= uuidv4(); //Trying to set the primary key "id"
 data.name = "Test";
 
 const dynamoDB = new DynamoDBClient;
 const result = await dynamoDB.putItem(data);
```

When I go check in the DB table, it shows `id : "229f0a06-7257-4727-b825-a6e8ea343b1e"`. How can I set the "id" so that it doesn't show up with double-quotes?

Thanks.

Comment: The ID is a string, so why wouldn't it show up with quotes?

Comment: It is string? The KeyType is HASH. Is it a string because uuidv4() returns a string? Well how do we add UUID as hash to the primary key field?

Comment: Key type is not the same thing as data type. The "key type" is what kind of key it is: it's a HASH key, as opposed to a RANGE key. Those are the key types. The "data type" can be anything you like that's supported by DynamoDB (string, number, or binary). In your case, it's a string.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I set the "id" so that it doesn't show up with double-quotes?

You don't want to.  Your Partition Key (= Hash Key) data type is `String`, which of course is the right data type for UUIDs.

`Hash Key` is a DynamoDB synonym for `Partition Key`.  As such, `HASH` [in the CreateTable KeySchema API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html#DDB-CreateTable-request-KeySchema) is not a data type, but rather is a reference to the `Partition Key` field.  The docs continue, *"the attributes in KeySchema must also be defined in the AttributeDefinitions"*, to a data type to one of `(S)tring`, `(N)umber` or `(B)inary`.